# Test is_int doen't work after passing $_POST var in simple $var

Tags: php, post, isnumeric

Is someone can explain me this..:

```
$bob = $_POST['foo'] ;
```

`is_int($bob)` FAIL but `is_numeric($bob)` is OK .

So i know i cannot use is_int directly on $_POST but here i transfert the post value in another variable before..

Whats wrong please ?!

Comment: Why you make a question that does not matter with the assumption? You write about `$_POST` but in your example you use `is_int` and `is_numeric` with `$bob`

Comment: so theres no ways to test is_int for a data coming to $_POST ??

Comment: Use `is_numeric` and if that is true, cast to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` values are strings, no matter whether they contain a numeric value or not. Just transferring them to a different variable doesn't change that.

You'd have to typecast the variable:

```
$bob = (int) $_POST['foo'];
```

but note that non-integer values are cast to `0` in this case.

Comment: thanks, so if i really need to test is_int , i need to do $bob = (int) $_POST['foo']; THEN if(is_int($bob)) , thats right ?!

Comment: @albatros that would not make sense: `(int)` will always create an integer. The problem is that it will convert any non-integer to 0. Do as PKeidel says above, test whether it is numeric first, then convert it into an int.